# Converting .htaccess files to nginx

Tags: php, .htaccess, nginx

I have next project structure: project directory and public folder. In project directory i have next .htaccess file:

```
AddDefaultCharset utf-8
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (.*) public/$1
```

And in public folder i have index.php and one more .htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule (.*) index.php?$1 [L,QSA]
```

How can i rewrite this rules to nginx?

I tried online resourses and they didn't help me:
charset utf-8;

```
location / {
  rewrite ^(.*)$ /public/$1;
  if (!-e $request_filename){
    rewrite ^(.*)$ /index.php?$1 break;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/files;
    charset utf-8;
    rewrite (.*) /public/$1;
    location /public/ {
        try_files /public$uri /public$uri/ /public/index.php?$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```

ALTHOUGH, by the looks of it, you simply need your `root` directive set to `public` and disrespect your "bad" .htaccess.
This will be a lot cleaner/more secure also:

```
server {
    server_name example.com;
    root /path/to/files/public;
    charset utf-8;
    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$uri$is_args$args;
    }
}
```